# How can I return tuple element

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

How can I write method getValue?
Is it possible? Please, help me.

```
template <typename... Args>
    class Base
    {
      private:
      std::tuple<Args...> v_tuple;

       public:
       /.../ getValue(const int a){
       return std::get<a>(v_tuple);
    }

    };
```

Comment: Note that at runtime type information is (mostly) gone. The function does not make any sense. If it was possible, don't your think `std::get` would work this way? :)

Comment: but 'a' is const int, so compiler know the value

Comment: The cv-modifiers in your function arguments determine the mode *inside* the function body. What you pass from the outside is irrelevant here as long as it looks like an `int` (constant or not).

Comment: `const int` as a parameter is a runtime-value that the method will not change, but the value is not (necessarily) known at compile-time. If you know the value at compile-time, make that a template-parameter, something like: `template< int A > auto getValue() const -> decltype(std::get<A>(this->v_tuple)) { return std::get<A>(v_tuple); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't because `a` would need to be a `constexpr` when passed to the function (and no, constructing a `const int` in the function body is not gonna help). You can use a template argument instead:

```
template<std::size_t I>
auto getValue() -> decltype(std::get<I>(v_tuple)) {
   return std::get<I>(v_tuple);
}
```